# ForEach() : Why can't use break/continue inside

Tags: c#, foreach, break, continue

Since ForEach() method loop through all list members, Why can't I use a **break/continue** clause while I can use them inside a normal foreach loop

```
lstTemp.ForEach(i=>
 {
   if (i == 3)
   break;
   //do sth
 }
);
```

Error:

> "No enclosing loop out of which to
> break or continue"

Comment: A well written ForEach extension should allow you to return false if you want it to break. But I can't say for sure since I don't know where you got your foreach. If you wrote it yourself that may be a good option.

Comment: Looks like you want the TakeWhile function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: I found a better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145563/list-foreach-break

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because `ForEach` is a method and not a regular `foreach` loop. The `ForEach` method is there for simple tasks, if you need to break or continue just iterate over `lstTemp` with a regular `foreach` loop.

Usually, `ForEach` is implemented like this:

```
public static ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Action<T> action)
{
  foreach(var i in input)
    action(i);
}
```

As it is a normal method call, `action` doesn't know anything about the enclosing `foreach`, thus you can't break.

Comment: Given that it's a method call, can I just return instead of break?

Comment: No, you will just return from the method itself. You will not be able to break out of an outer foreach that way.

Answer (score 25):

`return` will act as `continue` in `ForEach`.

Example:

```
var list = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4};
list.ForEach(i => 
    {
        if (i == 3)
            return;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
);
```

Prints 1, 2, 4.

3 - skipped.

Answer (score 17):

Presumably because you're using a lambda and the contents of the lambda are ignorant to the fact that it's being used inside a loop.

Answer (score 9):

rather than using a break, perform a filter first like this (it may not be the exact filter you need, but illustrates the point)

```
lstTemp.Where(i => i!= 3).ForEach(i=> // do sth);
```

Comment: -1 Not the samething. your code will run for every i != 3. The code presented will run until i == 3.

Comment: This seems the best way for 'continue'. Besides we can just write 'return' for 'break'.

Answer (score 5):

The way I'd explain it is this: `ForEach` is a **method**, not a *language feature*. The C# `foreach` construct is a feature of the language within which the other language constructs `break` and `continue` are permitted.

I would also point out (not trying to judge, just making an observation) that this is a good example of why some developers object to the use of a `ForEach` method: it doesn't really save typing in this simple case, it requires one more redirection than necessary, and it doesn't have all the functionality of `foreach` anyway.

In my opinion the main scenario in which a `ForEach` method makes sense is as an extension on `IEnumerable<T>`--to put at the end of a chain of method calls. It seems (to me) a bit strange that they added it to `List<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

To iterate only part of the items and emulate the break perfectly, you can use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
lstTemp.FirstOrDefault(i=>
 {
   if (i == 3)
       return true;

   //do stuff

   return false;
 }
);
```

For list with 100000 items, if the 10th item is 3 it will iterate only 10 times, using the `Where` solution will work, but iterate the whole list first.

Comment: The `Where` method does not iterate the collection, see: deferred execution.

Comment: @James maybe *iterate* isn't the right word.. but to find all matching items, somewhere somehow all items must be checked, isn't it?

Comment: Have a read of how the `yield` keyword works, because that's how LINQ queries operate. It's too long to explain here, but no, not all the items must be checked; only as many items as are requested by the call-chain will be checked. Exactly the same as your `FirstOrDefault`, which will iterate until it hits a match.

Answer (score 4):

Because ForEach is a method and not a regular foreach loop is need iterate over lstTemp with a regular foreach loop in case break, but in case continue use return inside the ForEach method.

```
var lstTemp = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4};
lstTemp.ForEach(i=>
{
     if (i == 3) return;
     //do sth
     Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```

Output: 1, 2, 4

Answer (score 2):

break and continue are C# language keywords that require compiler support. ForEach, to the C# compiler, is just a method.

Answer (score 0):

Because you delegate an action for each item in the list.