# Break foreach loop (WCF server/client)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, foreach, client-server

I have a simple code, which send from server to clients value to count. This loop count for 9 value, from 1 to 9. Everything work good for 1,3 or 9 clients. But for other number of clients when `i_wiersz` has value 9 and foreach loop want sent something to another client server break down. Ho make, to work with any one numbers of clients?

I try put inside foreach loop:

```
if(i_wiersz == 9)
   break;
```

but a get an error: Error

> Control cannot leave the body of an anonymous method or lambda
>   expression

My code:

```
bool spr_wiersz(int wiersz, int kolumna) //chck_roow(int roow, int column)
{
   wys_tab();
   int i_wiersz = 0;
   bool[] result = new bool[9];

   while (i_wiersz < 9)
   {
      subscribers.ForEach(delegate(ImessageCallback callback)
      {
          if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
          {
              result[i_wiersz] = callback.spr_wiersz(wiersz, kolumna, i_wiersz);
              i_wiersz++;
          }
      });

      for (int j = 0; j < i_wiersz; j++)
      {
          if (result[j] == false)
          {
             return false;
          }
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [_How do i exit a List<string>.ForEach loop when using an anonymous delegate?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557159/how-do-i-exit-a-liststring-foreach-loop-when-using-an-anonymous-delegate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can’t you simply convert it to a traditional `foreach`?

```
  foreach (IMessageCallback callback in subscribers)
  {
      if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
      {
          result[i_wiersz] = callback.spr_wiersz(wiersz, kolumna, i_wiersz);
          i_wiersz++;

          if (i_wiersz == 9)
              break;
      }
  }
```