# How can i exit the LINQ foreach loop when some condition fails

Tags: c#, linq

I've implemented LINQ foreach loop to execute some operation and if some condition fails in it i want to exit from that point and display an error to the user and don't want to go forward.

Below is sample code snippet.

```
myList.ForEach(number => 
{
  if (number.Value == null) 
  {
    isError = true;
    return;
  } 
  else if (a.SomeCondition()) 
  {
    //Do some execution
  }
});
```

But return keyword is not at all working, and even tried with break keyword no use. Need some one help.

Comment: using a simple old fashioned classic `foreach` ?

Comment: I see no benefit from using linq here.

Comment: This is not LINQ. ForEach is a instance method of `List<T>`. Not everything with a lambda expression is LINQ.

Comment: Eric Lippert (Previously head of the c# compiler team) - [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/):  The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. **Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects.**

Comment: What is `isError` about? You are talking about showing an error. Where do you want to show it? Inside the else?

Comment: Here I've given a simple sample so that's why it's looking like a normal iteration. But actually I need to iterate more items even million data.

Comment: @C4u I need to get out of the loop and show it on GUI, no need to iterate remaining items if error occurred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i exit a List<string>.ForEach loop when using an anonymous delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557159/how-do-i-exit-a-liststring-foreach-loop-when-using-an-anonymous-delegate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are certainly better off with a foreach statement so you can actually accomplish this. That said you could use a single bool to effectively skip the remaining iterations.

```
var keepGoing = true;
myList.ForEach(number => 
{
  if (keepGoing)
  {
    if (number.Value == null) 
    {
      isError = true;
      keepGoing = false;
    } 
    else if (a.SomeCondition()) 
    {
      //Do some execution
    }
  }
});
```

I recommend reading through this thread as well.
[List ForEach break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145563/list-foreach-break)

Comment: Is it fair to continue remaining iterations if something error occurred and that needs to be show it on GUI.

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, just use a normal `foreach` construct.  You gain nothing by using the `ForEach` method with a lambda.  If anything it's even a little less readable.

```
foreach (var number in myList)
{
    if (number.Value == null) 
    {
      isError = true;
      break;
    } 
    else if (a.SomeCondition()) 
    {
      //Do some execution
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I'm having huge data to loop and do some operation for each iteration.

Comment: @nag How is that relevant? How does it differ from what you do in a `ForEach` iteration? The only difference is that you can `break` out of a `foreach` loop, not out of the `ForEach` method.

Comment: @nag: What do you think the `ForEach` method does?  Do you think it magically performs better or avoids a loop somehow?  Have a look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,0e5a9cf0a310b9e5) and see for yourself that it's just a normal loop hidden inside a fancy method, but that makes it that much harder to control the flow of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use the Lambda ForEach() you can use this, but there is no way to *break* out of the statement.

```
myList.ForEach(number => 
{
  if (number.Value == null || isError) 
  {
    isError = true;
  } 
  else if (a.SomeCondition()) 
  {
    //Do some execution
  }
});
```

Comment: But it's unnecessarily iterating all the items, even if some error occurred i.e. suppose I'm having 100K items iterating one by one and i got error at first iteration itself then it's wasting of time to iterate remaining 99.99K??

Comment: First, I prefaced the answer with *If you absolutely must use the Lambda ForEach()* as there is no way to NOT iterate over all items using the Lambda ForEach() and secondly the accepted answer is logically the exact same answer as this.

Answer (score -1):

You may throw an exception and include myList.ForEach in a try/catch block.

Comment: Throwing an exception is expensive and is poor practice.  [Vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) - Boneheaded exceptions are your own darn fault, you could have prevented them and therefore they are bugs in your code. You should not catch them; doing so is hiding a bug in your code. Rather, you should write your code so that the exception cannot possibly happen in the first place, and therefore does not need to be caught.

Comment: It depends.  ForEach may be necessary (as opposed to foreach) due to closure semantics, and throwing exception may be cheaper than continuing the loop till the end.

Comment: @dvorn The closure semantics wouldn't be any different than using a `foreach` loop.  Actually stopping the loop is going to be faster than throwing an exception, if the performance is actually relevant.

Comment: @dvorn: Can you provide an example of where `ForEach` would be necessary as opposed to `foreach`?

Comment: It's still a valid answer to the question. THe asnwer should be edited to explain why it's a bad idea.